# InvalidateRect in Windows API, Charles Petzold checker4.c program

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Full program is here:

http://examples.oreilly.com/9781572319950/cd_contents/Chap07/Checker4/Checker4.c

The code in `ChildWndProc` that confuses me:

```
 case WM_LBUTTONDOWN :
      SetWindowLong (hwnd, 0, 1 ^ GetWindowLong (hwnd, 0)) ;
      SetFocus (hwnd) ;
      InvalidateRect (hwnd, NULL, FALSE) ;
      return 0 ;

           // For focus messages, invalidate the window for repaint

 case WM_SETFOCUS:
      idFocus = GetWindowLong (hwnd, GWL_ID) ;

           // Fall through

 case WM_KILLFOCUS:
      InvalidateRect (hwnd, NULL, TRUE) ;
      return 0 ;
```

Why in `ChildWndProc` in the case of message `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`:

the last statement before return 0 is `InvalidateRect`, since right before it the program sends `WM_SETFOCUS` message to itself with the `SetFocus` function, which falls through to `WM_KILLFOCUS`, which also has `InvalidateRect`, only the last argument is `TRUE`, instead of `FALSE`.

In my understanding the program should work properly without `InvalidateRect` in `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` since it calls `SetFocus`, which then makes it to invalidate the window, however when I comment out the `InvalidateRect` from `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, the program doesn't repaint the window properly after mouse clicks or button presses.

Why is this and why in the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` `InvalidateRect` the last argument is `FALSE` and in `WM_KILLFOCUS` it is `TRUE`?

I am running MS Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express in Windows XP 32bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `SetFocus()` doesn't unconditionally send an `WM_SETFOCUS` message. If the window already has the focus before the call, `SetFocus()` will not do anything.

Put another way, a `WM_SETFOCUS` message is only sent if the focus was changed.

As for the `TRUE`/`FALSE` parameter, that's `bErase`, whether to erase the whole window before re-drawing it, or whether to paint over what's already there. It is, in my book, a performance hack. If you know you can get away with not erasing the window (because you are just updating a small part of it), you can pass `TRUE` here.

I don't think that in 2015 there's much value in this optimization. If you need high performance display updates, you'd use OpenGL or DirectX anyway.

Comment: DirectX APIs change every few years whereas the standard GDI-functions within the WINAPI havent been changed significantly for decades now - so there is a big  reliability factor here; if your software needs to go though massive testing-cycles it cant be changed just because Microsoft felt the need to update DX again, some applications on this planet (quite a few, actually) need to be absolutely stable for longer periods of time - these are usually running without any acceleration which also maximizes portability to some extent, even the most demanding customer wants to update the OS sometime

Comment: GDI usually beats OpenGL or DirectX in terms of performance for regular GUIs. The overhead imposed by 3D APIs only starts to pay back, when you're rendering hundreds of thousands of primitives, applying lighting and 3D transformations. Likewise, Direct2D never really got off the ground, due to unacceptable performance characteristics.

Comment: @IInspectable: One reason for using OGL is to get double buffering to avoid flicker. I was under the impression that that's not possible (or at least not easy) using the GDI. Did I overlook something there?

Comment: GDI uses double buffering by default since Windows Vista. Prior to that, you could always allocate an offscreen drawing surface ([CreateCompatibleDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183489.aspx)) and [BitBlt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183370.aspx) that onto the drawing surface, achieving identical results.

Comment: Thanks for SetFocus() explanation, interestingly seems nor MSDN, nor Petzold in the book mention that WM_SETFOCUS is not sent if the window already has focus.

Comment: @Alpaca: With MSDN, you have to read between the lines a lot. [WM_SETFOCUS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): "Sent to a window after it has gained the keyboard focus." → maybe like it's only sent focus *changes* → confirmed by your example → must be true. There's a certain art to reading MSDN :-)